# Remove default installed files from IIS server using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, recursion, iis, directory

I enabled role IIS on Windows server 2012 r2 with administrator user. 
Now I want to remove following using powershell script:

1. `%systemdrive%\inetpub\AdminScripts`
2. `%systemdrive%\inetpub\scripts\IISSamples`
3. `%programfiles%\Common Files\System\msadc`

and the files/folders which includes following strings in their names: `iissamples`, `iisadmpwd`, `IISHelp`, `Printers`.

Comment: [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) seems like a good place to start

Comment: 1 and 2 comes from "IIS 6 Scripting Tools" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/discover-installed-components). If you don't need them, then uninstall that please. 3 shouldn't be part of IIS. You need to learn which component it belongs to and then see how to handle it.

Comment: msdac seems to be part of ole DB data access driver and there shouldn't have template anymore in2012 r2 so I think you don't have to delete it in 2012 r2 anymore.